# LED button doesn't work

Tags: gpio, python, led, wiring, breadboard

I have tried connecting a LED with a button like this (from "Adventures in RPi"), but with the far end of the button plugged at G (instead of F).
[image: breadboard]

And I ran it with the following Python program (by following instructions from the said book):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)
while True:
    if GPIO.input(24):
        GPIO.output(23, True)
    else:
        GPIO.output(23, False)
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

But when I tried running the program it didn't work. To debugg it I changed the if code block to this:

```
    print("button")
    ##GPIO.output(23, True)
```

And it resulted in many prints of "button"...

- How can I fix the program (or wiring?) so that the button will turn the LED on?

Thx in advance! :)

**EDIT:**
Here are photos of the actual wiring:
[image: photo of wiring 1]

Comment: Yes if you tell Python to print something, it will do so indefinitely unless you've written code to tell it otherwise.

Comment: There only a few things to go wrong. 1) the LED is the wrong way around, 2) the LED is not connected to GPIO 23.  Can you post a photo of your set-up?  Diagrams may show your intent - they do not show what you have done.

Comment: @Joan do you mind if I steal your phrasing above re: intent vs done? I like your wording better than mine.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Not at all, it'a a bit of a cliche. :-)

Comment: @SteveRobillard If you could steal Joan's sentence then she wouldn't be able to remember it anymore, right? Splitting hairs, I know...

Comment: @DarthVader I told him to onlyprint the string if the statement (GPIO.input(24)) is true, and he printed it altrough input24 wasn't supposed to be true (nobody pressed the button)...

Comment: Why does your button need a resistor if the Pi needs 3v3 logic and the board is 3v3 the gpio shouldn't have a problem handling the 50 or so miliamps the 3v3 line on the pi

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
from gpiozero import LED, Button
from signal import sleep
```

Then you can do

```
led = LED(24)
button = Button(23)
```

And do

```
button.when_pressed = led.on
button.when_released = led.off
pause()
```

This makes things simpler, and it might just work.

And are you sure your wires are lined up with your button? In the real photo it's hard to tell. Maybe you can try making the resistor under the LED? I don't know if your raspberry pi breadboard only goes one way or not. Plus, you do realize that 3 wires are going into the button in your wiring right? The yellow one, the black one and the blue one. I'm talking about the wires that are connected straight-up to the raspberry pi.

Comment: do you also want to use gpio.board